# Separate string by comma into a class

Tags: c#

I'm using a string which contains multiple values inside:
Example

```
string Response="John,13,1st,Mike,15,3st"...and so on
```

This 3 values need to be insert each value in separate class object.
Example

```
class Students
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string  SchoolClass{ get; set; }
}
```

I need to use my list as example

```
 Students mItems = new List<Students>();
 mItems.Add(new Students() { Name = first string value,Age=second,SchoolClass=third....and so on
```

Or if it is simpler using my string with key value method

Name:John,Age:13,SchoolClass:1st ..... and so on

Comment: If value order is certain then use Split method and assign values to properties from array.

Comment: So, what is your question? What *problem* did you experience? You now just described a *task*.

Comment: Yes order is specific. How i will do that? Is it better to use key value method?

Comment: Sounds like you need a CSV parser

Comment: `public string Age { get; set; }` type `int` would make more sense here

Comment: Or can i use json for this job?(sending title and value)?

Comment: Starting with an api request...Values are from a database. So i need to decode json and sending each value in my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.Split` and a for-loop:

```
List<Students> studentList = new  List<Students>();
string[] tokens = Response.Split(',');
for(int i  = 0; i <= tokens.Length - 3; i+=3)
{
    Students s = new Students {Name = tokens[i], Age = tokens[i + 1], SchoolClass = tokens[i + 2]};
    studentList.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you nice example!

Comment: @iBug: i noticed and flagged as spam. Btw, why there is there still no way to PM/notify someone?

Comment: @iBug: then you don't need to comment on a random post if you want to talk to someone. Especially because this isn't related to the question or answer and it's not interesting for others.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm fine with deleting these comments afterwards. I just like to remind others of inappropriate actions taken.

Comment: @iBug: sure, that workaround "works" but i don't understand why SO doesn't let communicate users directly (you could block someone if you get annoyed).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Possible Meta answer: *Repeat after me: Stack Overflow is not a social network*